# Event Identification in Series

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, data-mining

I've just posted [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63156/multiple-event-identification-in-a-series-segmentation-or-event-extraction) question on Data Science SE which asks about machine learning methods to identify "events" in series (time-series or otherwise). I'm wondering if I should consider regressions too?

The problem: I have series data, one variable is the continuous variable and the other is the measured variable. I want to identify any events that occur in the series.

Example: 
The input data can be shown as a graph

[image: Input]

The output should be used highlight any events in the series as such

[image]

My question here is, should I consider statistical methods (such as regressions) to solve this problem, or stick with machine learning? The method should be unsupervised, so I didn't consider regressions, but maybe I should?

For some example data, please see the question on Data Science.

Lastly, I don't think this post constitutes as cross-posting, as I am exploring a different route to the problem in the other question, but if you think am, please let me know.

Comment: The plots give the appearance of having different base levels between events. For this reason, I personally would use a sliding window, moving across the data from left to right and looking for the difference between max and min values in the window as being greater than some threshhold value to determine presence of absence of an event within the window. The threshold value could be determined from the difference in max and min values in the regions known not to have an event.

Comment: Thank you for the comment James, I'm not sure this method work for complex structures. The example above is just one small example from thousands of different series. I'm worried if the series was increasing rapidly, then the events would not be captured by your suggested method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical application of [Statistical Process Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control): you use the initial "in control" period to establish detection limits (e.g., by fitting a time series model to the data and calculating a one-step-ahead prediction interval), and whenever the series is outside these limits, you raise an alert.

This is actually supervised in a sense: given the data up to time $t$, you have an expectation for what should happen at time $t+1$, and if something unexpected happens, up goes the flag.

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into it but my initial thoughts are that this method might not be suitable as it requires a "base" for comparison. In reality, it might not be possible to define such a base for all cases, the example above is a simple illustration of the bigger problem, which could have a very complex series structure, without even considering the added "events". Thanks

Comment: Well, if your time series start out *in control*, then fitting a time series to them will model the *in control* status from the initial segment. Whether it works will depend on your time series, of course. I'd be optimistic for a series of the kind you have in your question.

Comment: I'm just wondering how this would behave with the events themselves. Consider left most red box on the second image in the question. How can this method determine the length of the event assuming an initial alert. Would it get confused with events that go higher than the "control" and then lower as in the left red box ? I really am trying to find an unsupervised method but haven't been successful this far.

Comment: It would raise a flag when the series went "out of control" for the first time. To detect the length of an event and distinguish it from multiple shorter events, I would assume some domain knowledge would be helpful. Or rather: [indispensable](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/2403/2853).

Answer (score 1):

Time series data can have both auto-projective structure as well as latent deterministic structure i.e. the presence and waiting to be doscovered structue (pulses, level/ste shifts,seasonal pulses and/or local time trends ). The idea here is to identify both.

Closely follow the work of Tsay here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and for a sometime useful software follow https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsoutliers/tsoutliers.pdf which requires the user to pre-specify the form of the auto-projective structure (arima).

If the arima structure is not known then one needs to SIMULTANEOUSLY identify both as suggested here https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf in aniterative self-checking manner